# I cannot fetch data from head of my sql table

Tags: php, pdo

As you can understand from the title, I cannot fetch data from first row of my SQL table.

This is my SQL table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvMIh.png)

and this is my webpage view:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDV9G.png)

I don't understand where I mistake. This is my code: ('reservasyon_cek' is an alias I use to get all the data.)

```
<?php
include 'admin_navbar.php';
$rezervasyonsor=$conn->prepare("select * from reservations");
    $rezervasyonsor->execute();
    $rezervasyoncek=$rezervasyonsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

I take all informations from SQL table with this and,

```
<?php 

                while($rezervasyoncek=$rezervasyonsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {?>
        <tr>
          <td style="overflow:hidden;
                              white-space:nowrap; ">
            <?php echo $rezervasyoncek['startDate'] ?>
          </td>
          <td style="overflow:hidden;
                              white-space:nowrap; ">
            <?php echo $rezervasyoncek['returnDate'] ?>
          </td>
          <td style="overflow:hidden;
                              white-space:nowrap; ">
            <?php echo $rezervasyoncek['carName'] ?>
          </td>
          <td style="overflow:hidden;
                              white-space:nowrap; ">
            <?php echo $rezervasyoncek['price'] ?>
          </td>
          <td style="overflow:hidden;
                              white-space:nowrap; ">
            <?php echo $rezervasyoncek['situation'] ?>

          <td>
            <center><a
                href="islem_admin_reservations.php?reservationid=<?php echo $rezervasyoncek['reservationid']; ?>"><button
                  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</button></a></center>
          </td>
          <td>
            <center><a href="islem_admin_reservations.php?reservationid=<?php echo $rezervasyoncek['reservationid']; ?>
                          &carid=<?php echo $rezervasyoncek['carid'] ?>&addStock=deleteReservation"><button
                  class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">End Reservation</button></a></center>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: You've already fetched the first result after your execute. When you get to your while loop, the pointer is on the 2nd result. Just remove the first `fetch()`

Comment: Why do you use `while` loop? If you used `foreach` it would iterate from start, not from the current row.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a prepared statement in your PDO when you are not binding any variables like an id to avoid SQL injection, this is the purpose of prepared statements. You need to use query.

You're code looks like this:

```
$rezervasyonsor = $conn->prepare("select * from reservations");
$rezervasyonsor->execute();
```

When it should look like this

```
$rezervasyonsor = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM reservations');
while ($row = $rezervasyonsor->fetch())
{
    echo $row['column'];
}
```

You can set your $row[] to a global variable to be used at this point. Or you can take the last `}` and you can put it at the bottom of your page and use  `<?php } ?>` and just echo the $row[] like you do in your code already.

To learn more about query and prepared statements visit https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Looking further in your code towards the bottom you already are using `<?php } ?>` so you have no use for using `<?php echo $rezervasyoncek['carid'] ?>` inside of that bracket, you're already inside the row loop.

Comment: your revised code does fix the problem but not because you query instead of execute, but because you haven't fetched before the loop

Comment: "You **need** to use `query`"?? Why?

Comment: I guess that is how I learned to do it. I have been using this guide https://phpdelusions.net/pdo for years.

Answer (score 0):

fetch gets the current record and advances the cursor to the next record

```
include 'admin_navbar.php';
$rezervasyonsor=$conn->prepare("select * from reservations");
$rezervasyonsor->execute();
//get the first record and move to second
$rezervasyoncek=$rezervasyonsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//get current and move to the next record
while($rezervasyoncek=$rezervasyonsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

hence you never see the first record because you fetch it before you run the loop

so just remove the first fetch and your loop should work as expected

i think what you have done is used a `do{}while` example but transposed it on to a `while{}` loop